# Getting Qt Test output in GitHub actions

Tags: c++, qt, testing, github-actions

Currently the only thing I can see is the executable exit code, so I can see if any tests failed or not, but I don't get any other output.

Is there a way to show something similar to what you see in Qt Creator when running tests?

I am using CMake and the Qt Test framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-junitxml` option to output test results to xml file(s) and use one of actions to watch detailed reports:

- [action-junit-report](https://github.com/mikepenz/action-junit-report)
- [publish-unit-test-results](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-unit-test-results)
- [junit-report-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/junit-report-action)
- [test-reporter](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/test-reporter)
- [report-junit-annotations-as-github-actions-annotations](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/report-junit-annotations-as-github-actions-annotations)

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I figured out too, just use an intermediate file. Do you have any idea why the Qt `stdout` test output is lost though?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. If you use the `-o filename,format` command line argument and output to a file, you can then use `more filename` to get the Test results.

GitHub actions uses Windows Server as the environment so that might be a reason for the weird behavior. My best guess is the Qt implementation works differently on Windows Server, because `std::out` works fine.